# SwiftUI scroll to top HStack Foreach

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a problem when trying to scroll to top a ScrollView. I use a ScrollViewReader inside a SCrollView and I subscribe with .onReceive() my lazyVStack to a property @PUlished scrollToTop from my view model. I see that it receives the notification properly but my Scroll doesn't move to top. Here is my code:

```
struct NewsList: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: NewsListViewModel
    @State var isDetailsViewShown = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    if !viewModel.isSearching {
                        TitleView(title: "News")
                            .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 11)
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 13)
                            .padding(.bottom, 0)
                    }
                    SearchView(searchText: $viewModel.searchText, isSearching: $viewModel.isSearching)
                        .padding([.trailing, .leading, .bottom], 13)
                    if !viewModel.isSearching {
                        TabsView(selected: $viewModel.selectedTab)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 13)
                    }
                    ScrollView {

                    ScrollViewReader { reader in
                        
                            LazyVStack(spacing: 15) {
                                ForEach(articles.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailsNewsView(article: articles[index])) {
                                        NewsCell(article: articles[index])
                                            .onAppear {
                                                checkActionForLastCell(index: index)
                                            }
                                    }.buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())
                                    
                                }
                            }.animation(nil)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                            .onReceive(viewModel.$scrollTop) { (scrollToTop) in
                                guard let first = articles.first, scrollToTop else { return}
                                reader.scrollTo(first, anchor: .top)
                                print(scrollToTop)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.background.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .onAppear {
                    //viewModel.getNews()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var articles: [Article] {
        guard viewModel.searchedArticles.isEmpty || viewModel.searchText.count < 3 else { return viewModel.searchedArticles}
        return viewModel.tabsArticles[viewModel.selectedTab] ?? []
    }
    
    func checkActionForLastCell(index: Int) {
        if index == articles.count - 1 {
            viewModel.getNextPageNews(isPaging: true)
        }
    }
}
```

and inside my ViewModel I just use a timer to see if it receives the notification

```
class NewsListViewModel: ObservableObject {
   /..../
    @Published var scrollTop = false

    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            self.scrollTop = true
        }
    }
}
```

I get printed the notification and the reader.scrollTo(first, anchor: .top) get executed... but my table is not scrolled to top.

Answer (score 1):

I may hace the solution to your question:

The `scrollTo` method takes the `id` you give it (in this case, `articles.first`) and tries to find a view that has a `id` modifier with the same identifier. But you haven't put the `id` modifier on any of the views in your `ScrollView`. You need to use the `id` modifier:

```
.id(index)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
ScrollViewReader { reader in
    LazyVStack(spacing: 15) {
        ForEach(articles.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailsNewsView(article: articles[index])) {
                NewsCell(article: articles[index])
                    .onAppear {
                        checkActionForLastCell(index: index)
                    }
            }
            //add line
            .id(index)
            .buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())
        }
    }
    .animation(nil)
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
    .onReceive(viewModel.$scrollTop) { (scrollToTop) in
        guard let first = articles.first, scrollToTop else { return}
        reader.scrollTo(first, anchor: .top)
        print(scrollToTop)
    }
}
```